# How to add fields when click on button in angular5

Tags: angular

When i click on the "Add-more-fields" button in the link below, the fields are adding only once. When I click a second time, the fields are hiding.

I need to append the fields. I mean I need to display fields, when I clicks the buttons number of times

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mz6aig?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: the sample is working as per you done code

Comment: You'd require a counter which increases when you click the button and then a loop to create as many input fields as high your counter is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **ngfor** to iterate the list of items based on the number of clicks,

You need to use array to carry the ng model value to component from html.

Check this working code It may required some of changes based on your requirements

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jzyfpk**

Comment: Yes it is working but Add-new-heading button is also repeating number of times. Button tag is there in html twice. when i remove one button tag nothing will shows.
I tried this.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krrq4m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not add fields, but change the variable `tmpo` from `undefined` to `1` when you click the first time, and from `1` to `2` the second time.

Your first *ngIf checks if the value is not 1, and undefined matches this criteria. Then you set it to 1, so it no longer matches and you go to block #temp where you show the button again, this time asking for tmpo not to be 2, which the value 1 matches. Next click you set tmpo to 2, so the first *ngIf matches again (tmpo (value:2) != 1).

So all in all you simply switch between those blocks. To add blocks, you'd need some array model to bind to.